# Can't use modulus on doubles?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, modulo

I have a program in C++ (compiled using g++). I'm trying to apply two doubles as operands to the modulus function, but I get the following error:

> error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'

Here's the code:

```
int main() {
    double x = 6.3;
    double y = 2;
    double z = x % y;
}
```

Comment: As has been noted, fmod() provides the necessary function.  As has not yet been noted, it's important to realize that rounding errors in the second operand of `fmod` may cause unexpected behaviors.  For example, `fmod(1, 0.1);` should mathematically be zero, but will in fact be almost 0.1.  The extent of error goes up with the magnitude of the quotient.  For example, `fmod(9E14, 0.1);` evaluates to about 0.05, which is from a mathematical standpoint just plain wrong.

Comment: @supercat more details would be awesome. I think have an idea of what's on behind the scenes to cause what you say to be true, but it would be good to see the reasons for why what you say is true; would be interesting to see how it works behind the scenes (I think I understand but could very easily be wrong).

Comment: Floating-point values represent exact integer multiples or fractions of powers of two.  For example, the integer literal 0.1 is exactly 3602879701896397/36028797018963968 (the latter value is a power of two).  `fmod(x,0.1)` will divide x by that precise fraction and take the remainder, rather than dividing by the numerical value "one tenth".

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why does modulus division (%) only work with integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6102948/253056)

Answer (score 339, accepted):

The `%` operator is for integers.  You're looking for the [`fmod()` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod).

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double x = 6.3;
    double y = 2.0;
    double z = std::fmod(x,y);

}
```

Comment: I am programming in C++ for Qt and fmod has a bug there. The result of fmod(angle, 360) can be 360 (WAT?!)

Comment: @Paul: That's probably not a bug. If `angle` is, say, `359.9999999`, then both `angle` and `fmod(angle, 360)` are likely to be displayed as `360`. (Add more 9s as needed.) Try printing the values with, say, 50 digits of precision.

Comment: @Paul Qt's QString::format will round. If it is that critical, you will either have to round yourself or check the output for "360" and replace it with your own value.

Comment: @Rohan `main(void)` is not necessary in `C++` (it's C legacy) and your edit isn't improving anything else either. I reverted it back.

Comment: This doesn't work for negative numbers. `std::fmod(-1.0, 2 * M_PI)` returns `-1.0`, I would expect approximately `5.28`.

Answer (score 40):

`fmod(x, y)` is the function you use.

Answer (score 8):

You can *implement your own modulus function* to do that for you:

```
double dmod(double x, double y) {
    return x - (int)(x/y) * y;
}
```

Then you can simply use `dmod(6.3, 2)` to get the remainder, `0.3`.

Comment: Still not a perfect solution. x=10.499999999999998, y=0.69999999999999996 returns 0.69999999999999929 instead of 0.0

Comment: @tarpista: That's expected, with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Use `fmod()` from `<cmath>`. If you do not want to include the C header file:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr double dmod (T x, U mod)
{
    return !mod ? x : x - mod * static_cast<long long>(x / mod);
}

//Usage:
double z = dmod<double, unsigned int>(14.3, 4);
double z = dmod<long, float>(14, 4.6);
//This also works:
double z = dmod(14.7, 0.3);
double z = dmod(14.7, 0);
double z = dmod(0, 0.3f);
double z = dmod(myFirstVariable, someOtherVariable);
```

Comment: Why would you not want to include the C header file? That's what it's there for.

Comment: No harm in putting the code in the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that also works with both positive and negative numbers:

```
#include <cmath>

inline double nmod(double x, double y) {
    return std::fmod(std::fmod(x, y) + y, y);
}
```

It will always return a positive number if `x` is negative or positive.

Note that if `y` is negative, the returned value will be negative. If you need a function that will return a positive in any case, then one need to use [`std::fabs()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs) on `y`, i.e.:

```
inline double nmod2(double x, double y) {
    return std::fmod(std::fmod(x, y) + std::fabs(y), y);
}
```