# How to calculate mod of log(n) for large values of n

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, computer-science

I have to solve a problem in C++, in which I have to calculate a modulus of a number formed as 10^n. But the problem is that n is a floating point number so if I calculate 10^n as pow(10.0, n) then it might overflow. So I'm seeking for a solution which can calculate 10^n mod m without any overflow problem. I'm normally use Python, where it's very straightforward, I don't know how to solve in C++.

Comment: Modulus is not defined for floating-point numbers : if the exponent is floating-point, then the expression `X^e` could result in floating-point.

Comment: log(n) != 10^n...  Do you mean exp(n)?

Comment: my mistake, I have edited the question. If I am given with n = log(num) then I want to find 10^n % m, where n may be a floating point number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use modulus on doubles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138790/cant-use-modulus-on-doubles)

Comment: I checked for floating numbers we can use fmod. So now, if we use fmod instead normal % operator then how can we calculate for large values of n?

Comment: 10^7.5 is about 31622776.601683793319988935444327 what answer do you want when taking this mod 6 ?

Comment: I expect 4.6. In Python I checked pow(10, 7.5) % 6 -> 4.6 while in C++ if I use fmod then I get 4. But I expect 4.6 and I want to achieve in C++.

Comment: You will need a big floating point form to handle this.

Answer (score -2):

How about [rounding](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/) first, storing the digits smaller than 1 in a float variable (you will get them by substracting the rounded variable from the original float) and then do the modulo with the rounded value. Afterwards add up the float variable

Will this solve your problem?

EDIT (see comment and for better look ;-)  )

```
 10^7.4 = 25118864.315[...]
 --> round = 25118864,
     float = 0.315,
     round % 6 = 2,

 --> (10^7.4)%6 = 2 + 0.315 = 2.315
```

as calc at windows would give you

Comment: Consider this e.g. 10^7.4 mod 6. So the float value is 0.6 and rounded value is 7. 10^7 mod 6 gives 4 and if we add float value it is 4.6. And the right answer is 2.315.

Comment: for better understanding ... 10^7.4 = 25118864.315[...] --> round = 25118864, float = 0.315, round % 6 = 2, (10^7.4)%6 = 2 + 0.315 = 2.315 which is what calc at windows would give you

Comment: But as I mentioned in my question, n may be large so if I do it in C++, it might overflow. How will I handle that situation?

Comment: normally to prevent overflow you use log() in numerics. You could maybe implement an if greater than 10^5 or so, and then use log() before round, ... but the difficulty is then to implement modulo correctly transformed to log

Comment: Yes, I started my question that way if you look at my edited history. Still looking for an answer.