# Error while using modulus operator in qt on double

Tags: c++

I have following code in my qt program :

```
        lambda = lambda % 360.0  + dphi ;
```

And I am getting following error while compiling: 
/home/vijay13/Downloads/app/app/skyobjects/ksmoon.cpp:389: error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'

Can someone please help me get modulus of given double in qt/c++ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use modulus on doubles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138790/cant-use-modulus-on-doubles)

Comment: it is not a qt related question

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to with Qt. The fact of the matter is that the `%` operator can't be applied to `double`.

For more information, and a possible solution, see: [Can't use modulus on doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138790/cant-use-modulus-on-doubles)

Answer (score 1):

This is because built in `%` is for integers. You can use `fmod` from `cmath` library for non-integers.