# Best way to handle 360 degree range

Tags: c++, sql, qt4

I need to select a range from 0 to 359.9 degrees in a SQL database.

My in put is in the form of a center angle and a range.
For example center=100 range=50 would give me a range of angle>75 angle<125.  However if center=0, then the range would be  angle<25 and angle>335.

Thus my current algorithm works like this:

```
minangle = center-range/2
maxangle = center+range/2
if minangle<0, then minangle += 360
if maxangle>0, then maxangle -=360
```

Then in my query

```
if minangle<maxangle, I query angle>minangle AND angle<maxangle
if minangle>maxangle, I query angle>minangle OR angle<maxangle
```

This approach seems to be a bit convoluted.  Is there a better approach?

Comment: use modulo math. `(angle + range) % 360`. the remainder will be the proper 0->360 angle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138790/cant-use-modulus-on-doubles . For floats and doubles use fmod.

Comment: That helps with the +360 -360 logic.  I was really hoping to have some way to avoid the (minangle>maxangle) and changing from and to or logic

Answer (score 0):

Change angle range to 0-720. Always keep minAngle < maxAngle.

if(min > max)
   max += 360;

minAngle = 50 , maxAngle = 200; => ok

minAngle = 200, maxAngle = 50;   => minAngle = 200, maxAngle = 360+50 = 410; => ok

although this increases your complexity.

Comment: I can't change the angle range, thats the input I'm looking for.  And yes, it does increase the complexity.  Perhaps there isn't a less complex way.