# why double v2 = ((double)51/4)%2 is an illegal expression ni c++?

Tags: c++, arithmetic-expressions

I'm new to C++ and is trying to learn the concept of arithmetic operators. Could someone please tell me why statement 1 is legal while statement 2 is illegal?

Statement 1:

```
double v1 = (double)51/4;
```

Statement 2:

```
double v2 = ((double)51/4)%2;
```

Comment: Because finding the remainder is integer operation.

Answer (score 1):

In statement 2 you are using the modulus operator `%` on a double and an integer, however the modulus operator only works on integer-values.

More info here: [Can't use modulus on doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138790/cant-use-modulus-on-doubles)