# Invalid operands error while calculating consecutive not free square numbers

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program in C to find the *k'th continuing not free square numbers*.

For example if `k=3` it will print `48,49,50`.

However I'm constantly hitting this error:

```
[Error] invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'
```

The error is in this line: `if (x % pow(j, 2)=0)`

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define K 6

int main()
{
    int i,j,x;
    while(i!=0)
    {
        for (x=4; x<=1000000000; x++)
        for(j=2; j<=113; j++)
        {
            if (x % pow(j, 2)=0)
            {
                printf("%d",x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the idea behind  (x % pow(j, 2)=0) is that any not free square number(y) has a divisible number(for example, x)  which can be created by a pow(x, 2)  and that pow number can be multiplied with a (z) number to make y

Comment: Please explain clearer what you are doing from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: for example both 48,49,50 => 48=(4x4)x3 , 49=(7x7)x1 , 50=(5x5)x2,    and please don't forget that 48,49,50 are 3 continuing not free square numbers , that kind of solution i want to make my program finds

Comment: if you Dirk Horsten  don't understand my comments its ok , but please focus to help me with the error "[Error] invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator%' " in the line of code "if (x % pow(j, 2)=0)"

Comment: This is no chat box in which old conversations are forgotten, charis. We are building a knowledge base for future reference. Therefore, we must improve the questions even if we understand them.

Comment: The error message is very precise and unambiguous. What exactly is unclear about it?

Answer (score 1):

- A single equality sign in **C** is assigning the value form the right to the variable on the left. For comparison, use a dounle equality sign.
- As soon as you have a bug you do not understand, instead of relying on the [precedence of operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), add brackets
- The `%` operator works on integers and `pow` [returns a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138790/cant-use-modulus-on-doubles), so you have to cast your result to an integer

Try replacing `if (x % pow(j, 2)=0)` by `if ((x % (int) pow(j, 2))==0)`.

Comment: your code did not do anythink.I tested it. Its very complicated for using pow because it takes int numbers and pull out double so that's the why I use j*j instead of pow(j, 2)

Comment: but the problem with pow is still unfixed

Comment: the error is [Error] invalid operands of types 'int' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'