# C++ why it's not possible to combine these 2 operations in 1 line?

Tags: c++, floor, modulo

Given:

```
double d;
int lsb;
```

The following compiles:

```
lsb = (floor(d));
lsb = lsb % 10;
```

However the following does not:

```
lsb = (floor(d)) % 10;
```

IDE underlines the beginning of `floor` and reports:

> expression must have integral or unscoped enum type.

Comment: hello, i think it is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138790/cant-use-modulus-on-doubles)

Comment: @FranckNgako you can flag the question as duplicate...

Answer (score 11):

You can combine those two lines, but this would need a cast:

```
lsb = static_cast<int>(floor(d)) % 10;
```

The reason why is the existence of multiple overloads of [`std::floor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor); note the following:

```
double      floor( double arg );
```

Hence, `floor(d)` is a `double` and cannot be used directly (without a cast to `int`) with the modulo operator.

Answer (score 2):

[`(floor(d))` returns a `double`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/floor/)  which you cast into a `int` by storing it in `lsb`

This `int` is good for `%`. If you don't cast it into `int`, it will fail.

Answer (score 2):

In this expression statement

```
lsb = lsb % 10;
```

the both operands of the operator `%` have an integer type.

While in this expression statement

```
lsb = (floor(d)) % 10;
```

one operand of the operator `%` has a float type and the second operand has an integer type.

The operator `%` is defined only for integer types or for unscoped enumerations.

From the C++ (2014) Standard (5.6 Multiplicative operators)

> 2 The operands of * and / shall have arithmetic or unscoped
>   enumeration type; **the operands of % shall have integral or unscoped
>   enumeration type**. The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on
>   the operands and determine the type of the result.

You could cast the first operand to the type `int` to make the expression correct.

Answer (score 1):

operator `%` required integral type (like `int`).

When you write `lsb % 10`, `lsb` is of type `int` so everything works fine.

However, `floor(d)` returns `double`, so when you write `(floor(d)) % 10` you're trying to use operator `%` with a floating point type which is an error.

So in order to use operator `%` you need to convert that `double` to `int`, like this:

```
lsb = int(floor(d)) % 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

`floor` is actually a function that returns a floating-point type, in C++11:

```
     double floor (double x);
      float floor (float x);
long double floor (long double x);
     double floor (T x);           // additional overloads for integral types
```

By assigning `floor(d)` to `lsb`, you first get a `double` which represents the floored value of `d`, then you automatically cast it to `int`. You need to be explicit about this if you want to combine it into one expression:

```
double d;
int lsb = ((int)floor(d)) % 10;
```

or

```
int lsb = (static_cast<int>(floor(d))) % 10;
```