# Why is there no division remainder operation for floats/doubles in C and C++?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, division

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does modulus division (`%`) only work with integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102948/why-does-modulus-division-only-work-with-integers)

This code doesn't work in C and C++ but works in C# and Java:

```
float x = 3.4f % 1.1f;
double x = 3.4 % 1.1;
```

Also, division remainder is defined for reals in Python.

What is the reason this operation is not defined for floats and doubles in C and C++?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The C committee explained its position of why there is no remainder operator for floating types in the [Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) document:

> *(6.5.5 Multiplicative operators)* The C89 Committee rejected extending the % operator to work on floating types as such usage would duplicate the facility provided by fmod (see §7.12.10.1).

Comment: Any insight as to why they made that decision?

Comment: @Remiel because *as such usage would duplicate the facility provided by fmod*

Comment: Yes, I read the answer. Let me rephrase my question: as a matter of language design, why would it be undesirable to integrate the facility of fmod into the core language?