# error: invalid operands to binary % when taking modulus of float

Tags: c

Its been a fairly long week, so forgive me if I am being thick.

I have some code like:

```
float someFloat = 0;
//....do some stuff to someFloat
//....

if( someFloat % 1)
{
   //take some action
}
```

I get a compiler error : `error: invalid operands to binary %`

Assuming the compiler isnt on drugs, whats wrong with this?

EDIT: As an aside, what I actually wanted to do was detect non-integer value and round up.
What I should have been doing was calling roundf (and I guess checking if the return is less than the operand and then incrementing if so, to take care that we have rounded up)

Comment: Answer is already there. For some more question like _Why not working on float_? please have a look on [why-does-modulus-division-only-work-with-integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102948/why-does-modulus-division-only-work-with-integers)

Comment: To round up if there is **any** non-zero fraction part, use `ceilf`, not `roundf`. Note: `ceilf` rounds toward infinity; if you want negative numbers rounded toward —infinity (e.g., —3.25 to —4), you will need additional code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thats almost exactly what I want. I dont have it on my target though, so i guess its the double version `ceil` for me...

Comment: Look in your C manual under `%`. It will say what the valid operands are. See if `float` is listed as a valid operand. (Spoiler alert: It's not.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`%` is an integer operator - use [fmod](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fmod) or [fmodf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fmod) for doubles or floats.

Alternatively if you expect your float to represent integer values then convert it to an `int` first, e.g.:

```
if ((int)someFloat % 2 == 1) // if f is an odd integer value
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Huh, I never knew that. Only been doing this 15 years.... Just had a look in my trusty old K&R, and that is so.

Comment: 30 years for me, and still learning... ;-)

Comment: @PaulR as with practically any other science, we can never completely learn a language. :)

Comment: True - of course after 30 years you begin to suspect that there are some things that you once knew, then forgot, then had to learn again... ;-)

Comment: @Paul R thanks for fmod hint

Answer (score 3):

The modulus operator only works on integers. For floating point values use [`fmod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20dckbeh.aspx) or `fmodf`.

Comment: @downvoter (we both know who you are): Hey there! That was really mature.

Answer (score 2):

% this only works with integers use fmod for floating point or double values**

```
double fmod(double x, double y)


x -- This is the floating point value with the division numerator i.e. x.

y -- This is the floating point value with the division denominator i.e. y.
```