# C program to print all the prime numbers from 1-300

Tags: c

I have written this code for C to print prime numbers from 1-300

GNU GCC Compiler shows the following error:

> error: invalid operands to binary % (have ‘double’ and ‘int’)

```
if (sqrt(num) == 0 || sqrt(num) % 2 != 0)
```

My code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  /*Created by Suvid Singhal                       Date:- January 2, 2017*/
  int num;
  printf("Welcome to 1-300 prime numbers C Program!!!");
  for (num = 0; num <= 300; num++) {
    if (sqrt(num) == 0 || sqrt(num) % 2 != 0) {
      printf("%d\n", num);
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%` only works with integers, but `sqrt(num)` is floating point

Comment: `sqrt(num)` returns a double. What do you want `sqrt(num) % 2 != 0` to do?

Comment: Have you checked the return type of sqrt ?

Comment: What do you expect `sqrt(num) % 2` to do?   And how is that helping to determine if `num` is prime?

Answer (score 4):

You have lots of thing going wrong in your answer.

Let's check them one by one.

- Your idea about prime number is not clear. A prime number has no divisior except the number and 1. (1 is not a prime number).

### How to check if a number is prime or not?

You can check all the `numbers <=square root of (x). So you need to check if someone (except 1 ) divides the number. If yes then it is not prime else it is.

### Implementation Details

```
int check= 0;
for(int i=2;i<=(int) sqrt(x);i+=1)
  if(n%i == 0)
  { 
     check = 1;
     n is non-prime;
     break; // no need to check 
  }
if(check == 0)
  n is prime
```

### sqrt() return double  and ...

Modulous can be applied over an `int` so you have to cast it to that.

### If you want to avoid it all

```
for(int i=2;i*i<=x;i++)
...
```

### For you to study

Learn about sieve method to get the primes. For 300 numbers probably it doesn't matter what you use but in case it is `10000000` then you will definitely want to give it a read.

Answer (score 0):

% operator is for integers. You may want to use [fmod()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) or an integer cast.

`if ( sqrt( num ) == 0 || fmod( sqrt( num ), 2 ) != 0 )`

or

`if ( sqrt( num ) == 0 || (int) sqrt( num ) % 2 != 0 )`

This should fix your compilation errors.

ps: If you are looking for an awesome way to generate prime numbers, see [Sieve of Erastosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 0):

In the code sample you have given, it is not quite clear how you intend to determine whether a number is prime or not. You have the following condition `if (sqrt(num) == 0 || sqrt(num) % 2 != 0)` to apparently determine a number as prime. But this condition is syntactically invalid. As others have pointed out, you can't do modulo operation on a non-int number as returned by the sqrt function. What value, do you think, is returned by the operation `sqrt(num) % 2` and what has it do with a number being prime? Your usage of `continue` has also no importance. Maybe you are a little confused between `break` and `continue`. I am giving you a sample program. Try to learn what your mistakes are from this:

```
int isPrime = 1;
for(int i=2;i<=300;i++) {
    isPrime = 1;
    for(int j=2; j!=i && j <= ceil(sqrt(i));j++) {
        if(i%j == 0) {
            //Not a prime number
            isPrime = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isPrime) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing

```
if( sqrt(num) == 0 || sqrt(num) % 2!=0 )
```

to

```
if( sqrt(num) == 0 || (int)sqrt(num) % 2!=0 )
```

Should fix compilation errors. See [error: invalid operands to binary % when taking modulus of float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317295/error-invalid-operands-to-binary-when-taking-modulus-of-float) for more info.