# Problems with modulo operation in Python for computing gcd

Tags: python, numpy

I discovered some strange behavior of the python modulo operation. The command

```
a = 1.0 % 0.1
```

yields

```
a == 0.09999999999999995
```

which is quite a big error that causes me problems when calculating the greatest common divisor of two float numbers. I suppose the error is related to the non-representatilty of 0.1 and 1.0 in binary (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). Does a workaround for this problem exist or can someone point me at a reliably function to compute the gcd of two numbers? The code that I have been using so far for computing the gcd is

```
def gcd(a, b):
    a, b = np.broadcast_arrays(a, b)
    a = a.copy()
    b = b.copy()
    pos = np.nonzero(b)[0]
    while len(pos) > 0:
        b2 = b[pos]
        a[pos], b[pos] = b2, a[pos] % b2
        pos = pos[b[pos]!=0]
    return a
```

I have the same problem when I use the fractions module.

Comment: Possible duplicate: < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102948/why-does-modulus-division-only-work-with-integers >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the  [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module.

```
from fractions import gcd
from decimal import Decimal
a,b  = 1.0,0.1
print(gcd(Decimal(str(a)),Decimal(str(b))))
0.1
a,b  = 22.8,9.3
print(gcd(Decimal(str(a)),Decimal(str(b))))
0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Decimal in python to not be dependent on float "errors".

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal as D
>>> a = D(1.0) % D(0.1)
>>> a
Decimal('0.09999999999999995003996389187')
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple hack that will work with normal numpy float arrays would be to multiply `a` and `b` by some large factor before taking the modulo:

```
def gcd(a, b, fac=1E12):
    a, b = np.broadcast_arrays(a, b)
    a = a.copy() * fac
    b = b.copy() * fac
    pos = np.nonzero(b)[0]
    while len(pos) > 0:
        b2 = b[pos]
        a[pos], b[pos] = b2, a[pos] % b2
        pos = pos[b[pos]!=0]
    return a / fac

print(gcd(np.r_[1.0, 22.8], np.r_[0.1, 9.3]))
# [ 0.1  0.3]
```

One advantage of this approach over using the `decimal` module is that you can still exploit the speed of numpy's vectorized array operations. Since `decimal.Decimal` can only represent scalars, you would otherwise have to loop over the elements in your input arrays and process them all individually.