# How do I fix the error ... invalid operands of types 'int' and 'float' to binary 'operator%'?

Tags: c++

I found answers for other operators but it seems like % has its own properties:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
float pprice;
cout << "Enter the purchase price =>" << endl;
cin >> pprice;
float cash = 10000%pprice;
return 0;
}
```

//Error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'float' to binary 'operator%'

This is only a sample of the code which displays the same error. Please how can I fix this error?

Comment: Closing as duplicate which explains the error, although I wonder if you meant `pprice % 10000` instead

Answer (score 2):

The `%` operator only works on type `int` [(See here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102948/why-does-modulus-division-only-work-with-integers). For float you need to use [`fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod).