# Decimal hour shows 4 min 60 seconds not 5 minutes

Tags: swift

I think the title says it all but let me go in to it a bit more.

I am storing decimal hours in a DB every 5 minutes while a user uses my app. I am having a bit of trouble displaying the correct time for some of the 5 min blocks in that it shows 4 min and 60 seconds. Every 3rd 5 min block shows this.

So something like this

```
4:60
10:00
15:00
19:60
```

Some even have n:59 instead of n:00

Part of the code is:

```
let hours = Int(floor(decimalHour))
let mins = Int(floor(decimalHour * 60) % 60)
let secs = Int(floor(decimalHour * 3600) % 60)
```

Any suggestions what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: `floor(x) % 60` will never give you 60 (or maybe it does for floating points? Try to convert to `int` before doing `%`) Please show more of the code. Also include what the value of `decimalHour` was for these test cases.

Comment: If possible, better store your duration as seconds (integer) instead of fractional hours (floating point).

Comment: Use `let mins = Int(floor(decimalHour * 60)) % 60`

Answer (score 4):

Binary floating point number can not represent all numbers
exactly, therefore your code is prone to rounding errors.
Example (Swift 2):

```
let decimalHour = 1.0 + 5.0/60.0

print(decimalHour.debugDescription) // 1.0833333333333333
print(floor(decimalHour * 3600)) // 3899.0

let hours = Int(floor(decimalHour))
let mins = Int(floor(decimalHour * 60) % 60)
let secs = Int(floor(decimalHour * 3600) % 60)

print(hours, mins, secs) // 1 5 59
```

The actual number stored in `decimalHour` is slightly less  than `1 + 5/60`, and therefore the seconds are calculated wrongly.

(Also note that you cannot use `%` with floating point numbers
in Swift 3, compare [What does "% is unavailable: Use truncatingRemainder instead" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495301/what-does-is-unavailable-use-truncatingremainder-instead-mean).)

As already said in the comments, a better approach would be
to store the duration as an integer (number of seconds).

If that is not possible, *round* the floating point number to
a the number of seconds and then continue with pure integer
arithmetic. Example (works with Swift 2+3):

```
let decimalHour = 1.0 + 5.0/60.0

let totalSeconds = lrint(decimalHour * 3600) // round to seconds
let hours = totalSeconds / 3600
let mins = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60
let secs = totalSeconds % 60

print(hours, mins, secs) // 1 5 0
```