# How to use % for float numbers?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to filter through a float number given by the user and find the largest digit within. However, I keep getting the error:

> error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'float' and 'int')

I have read other forums stating us the fmod function, how would I apply that with a simple piece of code that I just want to find the remainder of a float?

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: What would be the desired result of `%` on floats?

Comment: Use the `fmod` function from `math.h`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does modulus division (%) only work with integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102948/why-does-modulus-division-only-work-with-integers)

Comment: Floats usually don't have decimal digits, that's an illusion offered by default ways of printing them. Extracting decimal digits from them typically results in a bunch of junk.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You should include code showing what you've got.  Granted, in this case, it isn't compiling, but even a 10 line (or less) example should be provided.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `fmod` function ([Ideone example](http://ideone.com/BCTFlt)):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float val = 19.3;
    int div = 2;
    printf("%f\n", fmod(val, div));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The % operator is only applicable between integer numbers because in order to generate an integer quotient is required an integer division. Use instead:

```
double remainder = fmod(arg1, arg2);
```