# I want to find the modulus in a program that uses both float and int data-type (C++)

Tags: c++, int, double

I'm trying to find the modulus using the float instead of integer but it does not allow me to find it, i don't want to change it to integer either. The code is as follows.

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k;
   cout << "Hey victim, its time to do some simple maths which you absolutely love\nNow enter a number -_- (All only integers) : ";
    cin >> (a);
        cout << "You entered this: " << a << endl;
            cout << "Enter another number now!" << endl;
                cin >> (b);
                    cout << "You entered this: " << b << endl;
 c = a + b;
 cout << "The sum of "<< "'" << a << "'" << "+" << "'" << b << "'" << "=" << c << endl ;
 cout << "Now, type another number. lets multiply it with the sum !" << endl;
 cin >> (d);
 cout << "So, you entered this: " << d << endl;
 e = c * d;
 cout << "The product of the two numbers are -12" << endl;
 cout << "Haha, just kidding, the product the numbers" <<"'"<< c << "'" << "and" << "'" <<d<< "'" << "=" << e << endl;
 cout << "Well you got your answer, then why not subtract it? :)\nNow tell a number (and note that this number will be the which will be 'SUBTRACTED' " << endl;
 cin >> (f);
 cout << "So you entered this: " << f << endl;
g = e - f;
cout << "So the difference is " << "'" << e << "'" << "-" << "'" << f << "' = " << g << endl;
cout << "Now i feel like remainining in c++..\nOh and that 'reminds' of 'remainders'...\nYup now type an number so that we can find the remainder with the difference from the previous question\n(let this number be lesser than the difference and not 1)" << endl;
cin >> (h);
cout << "So you entered: " << h << endl;
i = g % h;
cout << "Hence the remainder when" << "'" << h << "' is divided by '" << g << "' =" << i << endl;
cout << "Now the last part comes, division, type a number which will be DIVIDED (try something divisible) ";
cin >> (j);
cout << "Sou you entered this: " << j << endl;
k = j / i;
 cout << "Hence the quotient when" << "'" << j << "' is divided by '" << i << "' = " << k << endl;
  cout << "This is the end of my small and simple math program, Hope you enjoyed it!" << endl;




system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: What is the first "it" in "*it does not allow me to find it*". Who is disallowing it?

Comment: The float data type say '%' is not allowed

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102948/why-does-modulus-division-only-work-with-integers

Comment: Use [`fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) instead of `%`.