# Getting "expression must have integral type" error when using Ternary Operator

Tags: c, conditional-operator

```
float sigma;
// ...
int kernel_size = ((6.0 * sigma) % 2 == 0) ? (6 * sigma + 1) : (6 * sigma);
```

In this line, I want to get the smallest integer bigger than 6*sigma value using ternary operator. By the way **sigma** is float.

1. I'm not sure that the above code is correct.
2. I also cannot compile, getting `expression must have integral type`.

Comment: Your code is definitely wrong because it doesn't compile.

Comment: [Why does modulus division (%) only work with integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6102948/817643)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is definitely wrong because it doesn't compile.

Using [`ceil(x)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ceil) (returns smallest integer not less than `x`), your calculation can be done like this:

```
float sigma;
// ...
float s6 = 6.0 * sigma;
float c = ceil(s6);
int kernel_size = c == s6 ? c + 1 : c;
```