# Modulo in simple calculator

Tags: c++, math, calculator

I have a simple calculator in c++ but I also want to add % operation for decimal division. I want to add 5 functions, addition, division, multiplication, subtraction. Everything works but decimal division no. I've got error when I trying to compile. Here is my code:

```c
# include <iostream>
# include <cmath>
# include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char operation;
    float number1, number2;
    float fmod;
    cout << "Enter operation +, -, *, / : ";
    cin >> operation;

    cout << "Enter two numbers: ";
    cin >> number1 >> number2;
    

    switch(operation)
    {
        case '+':
            cout << number1+number2;
            break;

        case '-':
            cout << number1-number2;
            break;

        case '*':
            cout << number1*number2;
            break;

        case '/':
            cout << number1/number2;
            break;
        
        case '%':
            cout << number1%number2;
            break;
            
        default:
            cout << "err";
            break;
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

Can anyone explain how I can add this function?

Comment: And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Did you get any compiler warnings when you turned them all on?

Comment: "37 26 C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\calc.cpp [Error] invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float' to binary 'operator%'"

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102948/why-does-modulus-division-only-work-with-integers

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operator cannot be used with float numbers. You can do this instead :

```
case '%':
    cout << fmodf(number1, number2);
    break;
```

Note however that it is not usual to use a modulo with float numbers on a calculator. So another thing you could do would be to round and cast the numbers :

```
case '%':
    cout << (int)roundf(number1) % (int)roundf(number2);
    break;
```

Comment: "it is not usual to use a modulo with float numbers" what else is `fmod` good for?

Comment: What if I want to get a few decimal places in the division?

Comment: @ idclev 463035818 You rarely found a modulo operator on a calculator and when you found one it works on integers, it's just what I meant : I didn't speak about C or C++ but about the OP project.

Comment: @Bazejoo In that case use fmodf. If needed you can also limit the number of decimals you print.

Comment: oh, understand. suggest: "Note however that it is not usual to use a modulo with float numbers on a calculator."

Comment: @ idclev 463035818 Did it, thanks.