# C++ - Improve computation time for complex number math

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I am trying to calculate complex numbers for a 2D array in C++. The code is running very slowly and I have narrowed down the main cause to be the exp function (the program runs quickly when I comment out that line, even though I have 4 nested loops).

```
int main() {

    typedef vector< complex<double> > complexVect;
    typedef vector<double> doubleVect;

    const int SIZE = 256;
    vector<doubleVect> phi_w(SIZE, doubleVect(SIZE));
    vector<complexVect> phi_k(SIZE, complexVect(SIZE));
    complex<double> i (0, 1), cmplx (0, 0);
    complex<double> temp;
    int x, y, t, k, w;
    double dk = 2.0*M_PI / (SIZE-1);
    double dt = M_PI / (SIZE-1);
    int xPos, yPos;
    double arg, arg2, arg4;
    complex<double> arg3;
    double angle;
    vector<complexVect> newImg(SIZE, complexVect(SIZE));

    for (x = 0; x < SIZE; ++x) {
        xPos = -127 + x;
        for (y = 0; y < SIZE; ++y) {
            yPos = -127 + y;
            for (t = 0; t < SIZE; ++t) {
                temp = cmplx;
                angle = dt * t;
                arg = xPos * cos(angle) + yPos * sin(angle);
                for (k = 0; k < SIZE; ++k) {
                    arg2 = -M_PI + dk*k;
                    arg3 = exp(-i * arg * arg2);
                    arg4 = abs(arg) * M_PI / (abs(arg) + M_PI);
                    temp = temp + arg4 * arg3 * phi_k[k][t];
                }
            }
            newImg[y][x] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can improve computation time? I have tried using the following helper function but it doesn't noticeably help.

```
complex<double> complexexp(double arg) {
    complex<double> temp (sin(arg), cos(arg));
    return temp;
}
```

I am using clang++ to compile my code

edit: I think the problem is the fact that I'm trying to calculate complex numbers. Would it be faster if I just used Euler's formula to calculate the real and imaginary parts in separate arrays and not have to deal with the complex class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most costly function calls were sin()/cos(). I suspect that calling exp() with a complex number argument calls those functions in the background.

To retain precision, the function will compute very slowly and there doesn't seem to be a way around it. However, you could trade precision for accuracy, which seems to be what game developers would do: [sin and cos are slow, is there an alternatve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091837/sin-and-cos-are-slow-is-there-an-alternatve)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will work for you:

http://martin.ankerl.com/2007/02/11/optimized-exponential-functions-for-java/

Comment: won't help here, he's using eulers formula, AFAIK there's not even a way to calculate what e^ix with *out* eulers formula, he doesn't actually touch a exp() in this case, and instead uses sin(x) for imaginary and cos(x) for real.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look with callgrind.  The only marginal improvement (~1.3% with size = 50) I could find was to change:

```
temp = temp + arg4 * arg3 * phi_k[k][t];
```

to

```
temp += arg4 * arg3 * phi_k[k][t];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define number `e` as a constant and use `std::pow()` function

Comment: Why would that make a difference?